# Read mysql table until first comma

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I have this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE ( device LIKE '%".$device."%' AND version LIKE '%".$version."%' AND firmware LIKE '%".$firmware."%' ) LIMIT 1";
```

The table:

```
device | a, b, c, d
version | 2, 3, 4
firmware | 5
```

Now I want to have the first string from device(a),version(2) and firmware(5) til the first comma, or if there is no comma the whole text.

I thought of `explode()`, but I dont really know. I would prefer php, since I want to echo the numbers.

Comment: Normalize your data model, this should not be necessary. Whenever you're trying to implement your own micro-database inside a database, something is wrong.

Comment: here's an example of explode() usage: `$devices = explode(',', 'a, b, c, d'); echo trim($devices[0]);` will print a.

Comment: @yitwail: Nothing wrong with it... I guess :)

Comment: @Dor, nothing wrong as far as php syntax. as to DB design, that's a separate question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL solution:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`device`, ',', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, ',', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`firmware`, ',', 1)
FROM `tutorials` WHERE `id`=123 LIMIT 1 /*
    Why LIMIT? `id` should be unique */
```

PHP solution:

```
function first_value($str) {
    $pos = strpos($str, ',');
    if ($pos !== false)
        return substr($str, 0, $pos);
    return $str;
}
$q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `tutorials` WHERE `id`='. (int)$id .' LIMIT 1 ');
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($q);

$arr['device'] = first_value($arr['device']); // etc
```

But as being said by Kerrek SB, your should really normalize your table.

Comment: tailor made for a CSV column that's not normalized, for people who hate to make a new table with just one column to hold values for a different table, or 3 tables in this case for device, version, and firmware